# Can't mount ubuntu partition ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount

I have a problem, I can't boot **ubuntu 14.04**.

Now I boot ubuntu from a pendrive and when I want to mount the partition where is installed ubuntu appears a pop-up that says

> Unable to mount volume 23 GB, 
>   Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /media/ubuntu/3b180041-346e-42af-af4d-d0660bd7a690:

Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb5" "/media/ubuntu/3b180041-346e-42af-af4d-d0660bd7a690"` exited with

> non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb5,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so"

Please help me, I'm a noob. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Boot the computer with a live-dvd/usb.

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fsck -a /dev/sdb5
```